# cakePHP helper not working

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to work out why my helper isn't being found in my controller.

I'm getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function hash() on a non-object in /home/example/public_html/cake/app/Controller/CommentsController.php on line 26
```

This is my "helper" helper found in views/helpers

```
class HelperHelper extends AppHelper {

    public function hash($hash){
        return md5(sha1($hash."sha1777")."md5888");
    }
...
```

this is the commentscontroller:

```
class CommentsController extends AppController {

    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Helper');

$chk = $this->Helper->hash($this->request->data["Comment"]["qid"].$this->request->data["Comment"]["aid"]);
```

I can see the helper listed when I do the following just before:

When I print the helpers I can see it in the array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Html
    [1] => Form
    [2] => Helper
)
```

I don't understand why this isn't working... any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks, Tim

Comment: How did you name the helper file? Also, I'd avoid naming a helper "Helper", Cake may not like that...

Comment: Don't know if that is the source of your problem but IMO calling a helper 'helper' is kinda of asking for trouble·

Comment: thanks fir your comments, it was called something else previously and had the same problem :(

Comment: I named it supportHelper and FooHelper, still the same issue unfortunately :(

Comment: What version of cakephp are you using?

Comment: The docs suggest you should have App::uses('AppHelper', 'View/Helper'); in your helper file before your class

Comment: Helpers aren't meant to be called in controllers, but in views. You should use a component instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I got this one! Your helper isn't being found by your controller because helpers are extensions for the **View** layer. Components are the extensions of the **Controller** layer.

So if you want to use this helper in the controller as you trying, make it a component instead. Or move the formatting code to the view if it is formatting code.